# How to convert one object into another without blocking

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need to rewrite some spring code to reactive-spring. So there's a reactive spring repository service which provides on type of object. But the return type of mapping method is another one type, which depends on locale. Now there's a blocking algorithm which calls get method from repository then split result, then take String locale and then make from them all one response object. How can I combine it into one non-blocking chain of reactive methods?

I see that the only thing I have to wait is Mongo Db service which is kind of reactive, but I want to write code properly to make Spring framework block Mono itself. Here is the example code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class PhoneCheckController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageLocalization loc;

    @Autowired
    private PhoneCheckService service;

    @GetMapping("/check")
    public PhoneCheckResponse checkPhone(@Valid @ModelAttribute PhoneCheckRequest request, Locale locale) {
        PhoneCheckResult result = service.checkPhoneNumber(DtoTransformer.toParams(request)).block();
        return new PhoneCheckResponse(
                result.getViolationLevel(),
                loc.getMessage(result.getMessage(), locale)
        );
    }
}
```

I tried to make like this

```java
public Mono<PhoneCheckResponse> checkPhone(@Valid @ModelAttribute PhoneCheckRequest request, Locale locale) {
        PhoneCheckResult result = service.checkPhoneNumber(DtoTransformer.toParams(request));
        return Mono.just(new PhoneCheckResponse(
                result.getViolationLevel(), //reactive part I need put
                loc.getMessage(result.getMessage(), locale) //reactive part 
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: The service returns `Mono<PhoneCheckResult>`, not `PhoneCheckResult` like You assume in your rewritten code. And you need to call its map method to create the PhoneCheckResponse Mono

Comment: thank you. I rearranged code and now it works!